# perform mysql queries looping through array returned by preg_match_all

Tags: php, mysql, preg-match-all

I'm trying to extract hashtags from a string using `preg_match_all` and perform MySQL insertions with the array values using a `foreach` loop. But obviously it's not working yet, that's why I'm here.

My code is like:

```
<?php

$text = "this has a #hashtag a  #badhash-tag and a #goodhash_tag";
preg_match_all('/#[^\s]*/i', $text, $matches);

foreach($matches as $value){
    echo $value.'<br>'; // right now, im just trying to see if i can get individual array values and then will have to perform sql query here
}

?>
```

I know it's a bit naive but I can't figure it out. Please guide.

Comment: Danny Beckett, sorry for bad indentation and language. I'm not bad in english, just was in a hurry :) thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this for loop, the `$matches` is multidimensional array

```
 foreach($matches[0] as $value){
      echo $value.'<br>'; // right now, im just trying to see if i can get individual array values and then will have to perform sql query here
 }
```

working example http://codepad.viper-7.com/iEGvgh

output:

```
#hashtag
#badhash-tag
#goodhash_tag
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$text = "this has a #hashtag a  #badhash-tag and a #goodhash_tag";
preg_match_all('/#(?P<hash>\w+)/', $text, $matches);

 foreach($matches['hash'] as $val){
    echo $val;
    echo "<br>";
 }
```